# NuGet Package manager stuck on "Retrieving information..." on VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

Using VS 2013 with NuGet Package Manager installed, I can view all Installed packages, but when I pick Updates or Online, I get an endless busy indicator showing "Retrieving information..."

I've verified I have a good connection.  I uninstalled/reinstalled NuGet Package Manager.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It has happened to me many times but it seems to fix itself if I restart VS.  As well, I know that if I change what I am searching for via NuGet from Online to Updates that screws it up and stops it from working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NuGet staying 'Retrieving Information' or 'No results found' in VS 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810936/nuget-staying-retrieving-information-or-no-results-found-in-vs-2013)

Comment: Switching to VS2015 (from VS2013) fixed it for me.  In retrospect, it may have been the act of installing VS2015 that broke nuget in VS2013...

Answer (score 61):

I'm using VS 2013 and all of suggested solutions has failed.
I solved the problem by applying the following method :

1. Open package manager console in Visual Studio
2. Type: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

This will change the connection security protocol to nuget as specified in this article: [Deprecating TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on NuGet.org](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/)

Answer (score 7):

May be it will help someone. My problem was with Nuget Package Manager. I've just updated its version.

To update **Nuget Package Manager** you need go to the menu under *Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates tab -> Visual Studio Gallery*.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem and tried different solutions but none worked! So I am using this workaround.

1. Go to https://www.nuget.org
2. Search for the package you want to install, it would show you the command for installing the package.
3. Open package manager console in VS and run the command (make sure you select the right project). This will install the package for you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was a problem with NuGet not Visual Studio. The problem turns out to be that NuGet does not like proxy settings of any kind. Running a local proxy debugging tool such as  Fiddler will break NuGet! You’ll need to turn them off or uninstall them also ensure that the  environment variable  HTTP_PROXY is removed from your system settings. Also you will need to check your system proxy settings as well and make sure you are not using a proxy.

This has been documented else where and is the problem for a lot of folks out there!

Answer (score 2):

The following steps should help:

1. Open the [`nuget` website](https://www.nuget.org/)
2. You can select any package but I would suggest `EntityFramework`
3. Open your project then select Tools > library package manager > package manager console
4. paste this into the console: `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.4.4`
   After taking these steps your `nuget` will work but only for the current project.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open package manager console in Visual Studio
2. Type: [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

It works well

Comment: It works for me... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

there is some error in NuGet package manager in VS 2013. It's noticed and fixed by Microsoft, but we are waiting for new update of NuGet.

But there is some more reasons, why you stuck on "Retrieving information". First check your proxy and firewall settings. In my situation, we need to unblock something(it is in my work, so I don't know,what exactly) and after that I saw the updates.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this problem once I changed versions of Visual Studio. For whatever reason, the Nuget extension breaks during the installation process even though it seems to be installed in Visual Studio.  You basically need to reinstall Nuget, and I had to follow the instructions on this link to get things working again:

http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2013/07/30/upgrading-nuget-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it.aspx/

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem and it would hang for about an hour at times. How I get round it is go to download a package in the Manage Nuget packager and then right click on your project and click clean. The download pops up within 2 -20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open packet manager console in Visual Studio
2. Type: [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

its solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, tried different solutions but was unable to resolve the issue. Finally, I tried this method and resolve my problem.

1. Go to the NuGet website: https://www.nuget.org/
2. Copy the EntityFramework Package link (Latest Version Suggested)
3. Go to your project in Visual Studio > Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console
4. Paste copied link into the console and download