# NuGet staying 'Retrieving Information' or 'No results found' in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nugetgallery

All of a sudden, NuGet stopped working for all projects.  I've tried it on 4 different computers in the office, and all of them stopped working.

If I go to 'Manage NuGet Packages', it says 'No items found' when the node `Online > nuget.org` is selected.

This was working some time ago I last checked, and all of a sudden it stopped. Any ideas?

I am using Visual Studio 2013.  I've tried removing and reinstalling NuGet from Tools & Extensions, to no avail.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem as of today. Very frustrating.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Worked fine yesterday, today it's doing exactly what you describe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NuGet Package manager stuck on "Retrieving information..." on VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361374/nuget-package-manager-stuck-on-retrieving-information-on-vs-2013)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem here.

https://twitter.com/nuget/status/451324276172283904 they're on the case.

In the mean time I used this trick:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx

(just grabbed the cache from the various computers at the office and set up a common folder - that way we have something for later, too)

Comment: Awesome thanks, the Scott Hanselman tip works great ! You need to have worked with this package before, though...

Comment: Yes, we were missing a few sadly. Oh well, they've supposedly identified the issue: https://twitter.com/nuget/status/451338013516107776

Answer (score 5):

I started the VS with `/Log` parameter and in file `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml` there was a record that `packages\repositories.config` was read-only. So, I checked it out, and it worked.

Comment: In my case "Access to the path .\myapp\packages\repositories.config" was denied". BTW it's %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing ".\myapp\packages\repositories.config" from Read Only to Read Write.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Run As Administrator" when launching Visual Studio.